# Why is binding not working for a DataGrildTemplateColumn on a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` defined in a WPF UserControl (MVVM).
I am attempting to use `DataGridTemplateColumns` to define `DataGrid` content.

**Here is what my the data looks like in my ViewModel:**

```
public class CompanyClass
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public string Location { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<CompanyClass> CompanyList = // Fill with Data;
```

**Here is what the DataGrid definition looks like in XAML:**

```
<Grid Name="SampleGrid"
      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=NegativeAccountsBalances}" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <DataGrid Name="SampleDataGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList}"
            Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid,AncestorLevel=1}}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <TextBlock Name="txtCompanyName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

For some reason I can't seem to get the binding working for the `TextBlock` controls within my `DataTemplate`. I'm setting the `ItemSource` to the collection of "Company" contained in my ViewModel.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

I don't see any errors in the VS output window.
If I try to bind a `TextBlock` to a bogus value, I still don't see any errors.
Somehow I don't seem to have my binding set up correctly.

Can someone please point me the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Is CompanyList public or private? 2. Does CompanyList Actually have data (like, you debugged and saw that it has data)?

Comment: CompanyList is defined as public ObservableCollection<CompanyClass> CompanyList. Yes it does have data (debugged and verified). There is definitely a binding issue. If I use a bogus field name "FOO" to bind to, I do not see any exceptions/errors in my VS output window.

Comment: Please show how do you initialize the collection `CompanyList`. I have an idea of what you're missing.

Comment: Once again, as per previous comment. If I enter a bogus value into my binding, I do not see an exception.

Comment: MK: Yes, you were on to something. I needed to do an OnNotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyList") when I initialized the observable collection. I would have thought that it would catch the bogus binding despite that. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @JohnB, you're welcome. Please note that if you answer me in a comment without tagging me with the @ symbol, I don't receive a notification so probably I will not see your comment (and that's true for all the users)

Answer (score 0):

`CompanyList` is a field. You can't bind to fields. You can only bind to properties. It needs a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you initialize the `CompanyList` property only *once*, either in the constructor or by using the initializer syntax that was introduced in C#6:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CompanyList = new ObservableCollection<CompanyClass>();
        //popuoate collection...
        CompanyList.Add(new CompanyClass() { Name = "test...." });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<CompanyClass> CompanyList { get; private set; }
}
```

**C#6+:**

```
public ObservableCollection<CompanyClass> CompanyList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CompanyClass>();
```